# Update second amount of row with id based on the first id

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-update, window-functions

My original data is as follows:

```
sid id  amount
1   12  30
2   45  30
3   45  50
4   78  80
5   78  70
```

The desired output is follows:

```
sid id  amount
1   12  30
2   45  30
3   45  30
4   78  80
5   78  80
```

THe intention is to take the amount where id appears first and update the amount the second time it appears
I am trying the following code:

```
UPDATE foo AS f1
  JOIN
  ( SELECT cur.sl, cur.id,
           cur.amount AS balance 
    FROM foo AS cur
      JOIN foo AS prev
        ON prev.id = cur.id
    GROUP BY cur.tstamp
  ) AS p
  ON p.id = a.id
SET a.amount = p.amount ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table to a query that returns the min `sid` of each `id` and again to itself so that you get the rows with that min `sid`:

```
UPDATE tablename t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(sid) sid, id
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY id
) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.sid < t1.sid
INNER JOIN tablename t3 ON t3.sid = t2.sid
SET t1.amount = t3.amount;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ce05581e398acf7b1ee53361029207a).

For MySql 8.0+ you can do it with only 1 join if you use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
UPDATE tablename t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sid) rn
  FROM tablename
) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id  
SET t1.amount = t2.amount
WHERE t2.rn = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a57e37a19f6493756e379cb9aa652bef).